# Immutable Collections that return a new view when modified

Tags: java, collections

Firstly im not asking a question of a wrapper that makes the wrapped readonly such as Collections.unmodifableXXX. My api would have a different api where all modifier method would return the new collection.

Something like a simple list would no longer have void set methods but would return a new List.

Ideally the package would include the same immutable variations of List, Set, Map and even boring Stack.

UPDATE

```
// i am omitting generics etc to keep things simple.
XList list = List.fromArray( 1, 2, 3 );
XList list2 = list.add( 4 );

System.out.println( list ); // 1, 2, 3 
System.out.println( list2 ); // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

removes, sets etc all return a different List after updating elements etc.

Comment: Have you thought about using [Scala's](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)? Not sure how that would pan out in Java though....

Comment: What you are describing is called "copy-on-write".

Comment: @jimGarrison im asking that the instances remain immutable, your actually describing how COW work on the inside with regards to the backing array.

Comment: @jordao Its not pretty using scala classes within Java because of the lack of closures.

Comment: @mP: Take a look at [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) then...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think that the OP is describing a functional collections API.  This can be implemented using copy-on-write, but the key difference is in the API design itself.

I couldn't find an alternative Java collections framework that works like this.  This is not to say that you couldn't write one ...

(The standard Java copy-on-write collections are mutable, and behave like "ordinary" collections in most respects.  The purpose of using the copy-on-write mechanism in these classes is to allow concurrent iteration and modification, and reduces synchronization overheads on shared collections with a lot of thread contention.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called "copy-on-write", and Java has two implementations of such collections:  [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) and [CopyOnWriteArraySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html)

Comment: COWAL and COWAS dont return a new instance with the change. THis makes it impossible to use to hold a before and after version.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the copy on write collections from java 5?

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_8_copy_on_write.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The [Clojure programming language](http://clojure.org/) (which compiles to Java byte code, runs on the JVM, and is fully interoperable with Java) has collections with exactly the semantics you are looking for.

Here's an overview page describing the general principal behind Clojure's data structures: http://clojure.org/data_structures

Although Clojure has its own Lisp-like syntax, most of its library functions are implemented in Java. For example, Clojure lists are defined by [PersistentList.java](http://code.google.com/p/clojure/source/browse/trunk/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentList.java?r=1310). You could import and use this class in any Java program. Clojure has similar classes for Sets, Maps, etc...

Comment: For the moment this is almost a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it within the vanilla Collections framework, because e.g. `Collection.add(Object)` is specified to return a `boolean`, and you can't override it to return a new `Collection` instead.

You might try the data structures in [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/), perhaps.

Comment: I know other langs on the JVM have similar collections, but i was hoping to stay in java land.

Comment: `Functional Java` isn't another language, to my knowledge -- it's just a Java library.